# What would be a good way to abstract OpenGL-Concepts in a game engine?

Tags: c#, object-oriented, c++, game-development, opengl

I have posted the same question to StackOverflow and Stackexchange and both got downvoted to oblivion as "too broad". So maybe this will be a better place for it.

I am working on a rendering engine with my own C# bindings for OpenGL and I have a couple of questions when it comes to OpenGL's constructs and OOP concepts. Since I do not want to deal with buffers directly everytime I am rendering something, it would make sense to create a "Mesh" class that handles its own buffers.

What kind of structure would make sense for a rendering engine using OpenGL?

What are some of the classes I should have and what is their purpose? (VAO, VBO, Shader)

What kind of information should each of the classes be able to access? (Should a VAO handle it's own shader?)

Are there any simple, rendering architecture focused open source examples for how this could work?

Existing projects like Ogre3D, Delta and Godot are way to over-engineered for my purpose since they implement multiple layers of abstraction that focus on game development and I would like to get a grasp of the actual rendering aspect of it (ie: buffer- and shader-handling).

I know, I know. "Make a game, not an engine". But making an engine is exactly what I want. I want to know the details of how a pixel/fragment gets on the screen before diving into game development itself.

Answers using C++/C# would be prefered, but any kind of response is appreciated! Thank you! :)

Comment: What makes you think that the question gets narrower by copy&pasting it?

Comment: "*I would like to get a grasp of the actual rendering aspect of it (ie: buffer- and shader-handling)*" Then why do you need an abstraction at all? I mean, beyond basic, obvious abstractions, like possibly wrapping a couple of OpenGL objects in classes to make interaction slightly more convenient. But that's not really an abstraction; it's just a wrapper. And since it's for personal convenience, it's just whatever works for you, personally.

Answer (score 7):

You shouldn't abstract opengl, instead you should abstract your rendering engine.

Key components there are loading a mesh, setting parameters for the render rendering, queuing the mesh for render. Those parameters will have different frequency of change. The camera transform will change only once per frame, the object transform (and pose transform) will change for each object, the material properties is somewhere between that.

Doing this allows you to swap out the underlying API from opengl to DX10 to vulkan to DX12.

Comment: For a low-level API, one should wrap OpenGL objects inside classes in the used language, to enable more easy manipulation of them.